# use directives in angular schema form help fields

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm using Angular Schema Form and would like to be able to use directives in my form's help fields, e.g.

```
{
  type: "help",
  helpvalue: "<h1 ng-click='doSomething()'>Yo Ninja!</h1>"
}
```

However, in the HTML that is generated from this, the `ng-click='doSomething()'` is removed, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: The HTML belongs in your template, not your JSON model.

Comment: @BenHarold I don't think templates are supported for fields of type `help`